# Zurb Foundation 4 topbar fixed/sticky height issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 4 for a website, I've already used it, but I never tried the sticky or fixed topbar class.

The problem is that when I set up the sticky or the fixed class to my nav wrapper, when rendered in browser navbar's height become the double!
(I use a container because, from the documentation *"To make the top bar stay fixed as you scroll, wrap it in div class="fixed"* ")

Anyone knows why the topbar change its height with that classes? I really can't find out a solution!

Here is the code:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid fixed"> 
      <nav class="top-bar">
         <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
               <h1><a href="#">Title</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
         </ul>
       <section class="top-bar-section">     
         <ul class="right">
               <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
         </ul>
         </section>
      </nav>
   </div>
```

Comment: What is the css of your .fixed class ? Also why are you not using it on your nav ?

Comment: I have not added any custom css to .fixed class, it is a Zurb foundation one. Unfortunatly I'm not at home, tomorrow I'll write back for some news! Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

In your custom CSS, add the following :

```
.row{
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

This should result in a sticky header, with the correct padding for allowing content to begin under it.

Begin your content as usual with `<div class="row">content ... </div>`

Reference : http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.php#

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I'm not at home now, tomorrow morning I'll try and post back here! Have a nice night ;)

Comment: Ok, that doesnt work! If I create a top bar <div class="contain-to-grid"> without fixed class, and add your custom css, I have all rows padding affected, and my top-bar go away from the grid. Else, if I add your custom css AND also fixed/sticky class to the top bar, it's height contnues doubleing! Anyway, I'm going to search in zurb template's page to see if I can find a working example, and I'l post back! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

It seems that the problem is the wrapper div with `.contain-to-grid` class. If I remove it, I can have a perfectly working sticky/fixed topbar.

When I add that class, my top bar gets fat. In the defaults, I found that:

```
.contain-to-grid { width: 100%; background: #111111; }
.contain-to-grid .top-bar { margin-bottom: 1.875em; }
```

so I did an override

```
.contain-to-grid .top-bar { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
```

and now my top-bar is sticky, adjusting to the grid, and thin again!